# how to save two diffrent hours using TimePickerFragment

Tags: java, android, timepicker

I´m using `Time Pickerfrangment` to ask the user to start an hour and a final hour, so I have to save in different variables both times. how can I make an if to say: if this button is pressed save in the variable "x" and if it is the other, save in the variable "y".

My code is:

```
 public  class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the same picker for both start and final hour?

Comment: yes. mi idea is to make an if to know witch time the user is selecting the begening or the end